# Solarium user deprecated warning

Tags: solarium, nelmiosolariumbundle

I have this warning since I use Solarium for my project. Do you know how I can resolve it?

```
User Deprecated: Not passing an instance of AdapterInterface as the first constructor argument is
deprecated in Solarium 5.2 and will cause an error in Solarium 6.
```

Thx :D

Comment: What version of NelmioSolariumBundle are you using?